# GRPC C++ build/linker issues on Windows

Tags: c++, grpc, unresolved-external, grpc-c++

I'm on day three of trying to get a "simple" grpc application going but have hit the 15th roadblock.

So far I've:

- Managed to build and install GRPC using the instructions here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#windows-using-visual-studio-2019-or-later which resulted in me having GRPC installed to `C:\libs\grpc\grpc`
  [image]
- Generated my `.cc` and `.h` files using `protoc` and added them to my project
  [image]
- Added the GRPC install directory to the `Include` and `Library` directories
  [image]

However when I try to build my application I'm bombarded with errors related to unresolved external symbols
[image]

From my understanding of the error, I'm not linking to something that contains each of the symbols missing however given I've

Its been a long time since I've touched c++ so appologies if this is a simple issue

Comment: Why build from source? Why not let cmake handle it for you? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp

Comment: It looks like you forgot to tell the linker to actually _link_ with the GRPC libraries. It is not sufficient to tell it where the libraries live. See Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Comment: I somehow never stumbled on that page, I'm not super familiar with cmake but that seams like it'll be a good option. Am I misunderstanding that page or does this still build from source but cmake takes care of it in the background rather than manually building and linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more messing around I managed to get things working. @sweenish got me on the right track with suggesting using cmake and pointing me to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp however I did still need to build from source (which given https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/ starts with building GRPC from source, I believe is the intended way to go.)

Given I found so little useful info on how to end-to-end get a basic c++ GRPC app running, I figured I'd answer my question with a step by step of how to get things working so the next person has an easier time.

## Building GRPC on Windows

These steps are similar to those mentioned in https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/ however they will be targeting Windows

1. Pick a directory you'd like to install GRPC into and ensure it exists, I'll be using `C:\libs`.
2. Install the tools referenced in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#windows
3. Clone the GRPC repo `git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.60.0 --depth 1 --shallow-submodules https://github.com/grpc/grpc`
4. `cd` into the `grpc/cmake` directory. Make a new directory called `build` and cd into it. You should now be in `grpc/cmake/build` where `grpc` is the root directory of the repo you cloned
5. Initalise cmake, passing in the location you'll be installing GRPC to. `cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/libs" ../..` . Note the file path `/` is the worng way around for Windows (no idea if this matters but it works)
6. Build GRPC with `cmake --build . --config Release` - Go make a coffee, even on a high end machine this can take upwards of 30 mins. You may have some luck with `cmake --build . --config Release -- /m` speeding things up
7. Install GRPC with `cmake --install . --config Release`
8. If you want a Debug version then redo the previous step with `--config Debug`

If everything worked, GRPC should be installed in your directory of choice. An easy way to check is to go to `[INSTALL_DIR]\bin` and run `protoc.exe --version`, if you get something like `libprotoc 25.0` then you've successfully built GRPC for Windows.

## Compiling Applications with GRPC on WIndows

Compiling GRPC is half the battle, now we need to build an app that uses it to confirm everything is working. A good test is the `HelloWorld` app that comes as part of the repo you checked out in the previous step located at `grpc\examples\cpp\helloworld`. I'll go through both commandline and Visual Studio building as they are slightly different.

### Command Line

1. Change directory to `grpc\examples\cpp\helloworld`
2. Initalise cmake with `cmake "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/libs" .` . Make sure you replace `C:/libs` with your install location
3. Build the project with `cmake --build . --config Release`

The output directory structure is a bit of a mess but you should now have a helloworld server and client application at the following locations. Give them both a run to confirm everything is working

- `grpc\examples\cpp\helloworld\Release\greeter_server.exe`
- `grpc\examples\cpp\helloworld\Release\greeter_client.exe`

## Visual Studio 2022

Not sure if its needed but I'll mention it just incase, In Visual Studio Installer I have the default options for `Desktop development with C++` installed which includes `C++ CMake tools for Windows`.

1. Open Visual Studio and select `Open a local folder`
2. Open `grpc\examples\cpp\helloworld`
3. Click the configuration dropdown (currently set to `x64-Debug`) and select `Manage Configurations...`
4. In the `CMake command arguments` section add `"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/libs"` (including the quotes)
5. When you save, cmake will regenerate its cache.
6. In the Solution Explorer, click the purple icon (Switch between available views) to switch to the cmake targets view
7. Build and run a target

Hopefully all that helps someone oneday, time to start actually using GRPC with C++!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project missed required linker dependencies such as `grpc` and `grpc++`. You can specify it manually or let cmake do it for you.